# brownie deploying contract get transaction-receipt

Tags: contract-deployment, brownie

Is there a way to get the transaction-receipt when deploying a contract with contract.deploy()? The method returns the Contract object but i also want the transaction receipt.

Background: i want to log the gas-costs for deployment

Answer (score 0):

It's available under `tx` property of the Contract object.

```
contract = MyFancyContract.deploy(...)
receipt = contract.tx
```

https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html#Contract.tx